# GFortran Memory Errors not showing up under Valgrind

Tags: debugging, fortran, valgrind

I am trying to run some legacy fortran code that seems to have a memory issue.

I am not a fortran programmer and have never written a line of fortran.

Occasionally on my Mac, the program SIGABRTs on some inputs but on most inputs its works fine. However, on my Ubuntu machine, it always SIGABRTs even on files that it works fine on the Mac.

In order to try to track down the problem, I ran the program with valgrind on the Ubuntu machine.

```
valgrind ./a.out
```

Lo and behold, when the program runs under valgrind, it runs with no problems at all. Weird, right?

The error message I get when running it sans-valgrind:

```
 Within subroutine domdecision
 END OF ROUTINE 
*** Error in `./a.out': free(): invalid size: 0x0000000031043e80 ***

Program received signal SIGABRT: Process abort signal.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7FD269195777
#1  0x7FD269195D7E
#2  0x7FD268AE6D3F
#3  0x7FD268AE6CC9
#4  0x7FD268AEA0D7
#5  0x7FD268B23F23
#6  0x7FD268B301FD
#7  0x40C807 in domdecision_ at gnm-domdecomp.f:434
#8  0x404B2F in domdecomp_ at gnm-domdecomp.f:226
#9  0x40F9A5 in MAIN__ at gnm-domdecomp.f:47
```

And line 433-434 of gnm-domdecomp.f is:

```
real*8 dist,tdist
 -        ,wt(nmax),temp,ut(nmax,nmax)
```

which looks just like an array calculation.

So my questions are, 1. what is the probable error, 2. why does it disappear on certain machines and under valgrind, and 3. what should I do next to go about debugging this?

Comment: I'm sorry for this question, but I'm a fortran neophyte, to print the value of nmax would I use:  write (*,*) "NMax is ",nmax

Comment: Done. "nmax =          101"

Comment: 10,000 64-bit elements ain't so much.  Guessing wildly at the causes of transient problems in unseen code is a real shot in the dark ... All I can suggest is that you answer your own question 3 by breaking out your favourite debugger, rolling up your sleeves, and getting stuck in.

Comment: I was afraid of that, thanks.

Comment: I ended up recompiling with g77 (instead of gfortran) and the problem magically resolved itself.